# PL/SQL is executed by Oracle Database not the host system

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have just started with Basics of PL/SQL and encountered with this statement and I am unable to get this .Please guide .

Comment: Could you post the statement and error being encountered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood what you are saying, then: PL/SQL is executed within the database which is installed on the database server.

Although you can "save" your PL/SQL code into a script which resides on your hard disk (local PC), there's no use of it - it has to be "stored" in the database. That's why we call those procedures "stored procedures". True - there are anonymous PL/SQL blocks, but they also run in the database.

Opposed to those are .SQL scripts, files you can store to your hard disk and execute them "locally" by e.g. connecting to the database via SQL*Plus, a command line tool, and call those *locally* stored files (if that's what you call "host system").

Comment: Sir , I got your point but database server is called host system only so why is the statement like executed on Oracle database but not on host system ,At the end its the host system only which is executing the PL/SQL statement .

Comment: The term HOST SYSTEM is ambiguous. All the following can be considered host system: local script libraries, presentation layer be it web/html or other interface, application/business rules server, database server.  You often need to derive meaning from content. The statement in question actually takes this one-step further. The statement is stating it is the Oracle DBMS software is executing the PL/SQL as opposed to a SQLPlus script which is executed by the underlying operating system. As with many things CS a single term seldom has a single meaning.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation .

Comment: @Belayer, I think it important to point out that even with a simple sql script, no PL/SQL code in sight, while the script itself is being processed by some 'local' program (say, sqlplus, or SQL Dev) the actual sql statements are simply passed from that local program to the database for actual processing.  The only thing 'processed' by the local client is any commands to that client - like sqlplus 'set' or 'spool' commands.

Comment: Admittedly so! The point however being the every layer can be considered the host system. Unfortunately, an example can never  incorporate the full range of connections. Especially with 600 character limit.